# Question about Java Nodes, specifically with .next

Tags: java

```
public void insertIt (Node firstNode, Node newNode) {
 firstNode.next = newNode;
 newNode.next = null;   
}
```

I couldn't find the class that uses `.next`, can anyone show me? Also, I don't really understand this. I'm setting `firstNode.next=newNode`, so how would `firstNode` include `firstNode.next`? I hope that makes sense.

From my notes:

```
> Example 1 to practice with links: 
> Node node1 = new Node(22); Node node2
> = new Node(44); firstNode = node1; node1.next = node2; node2.next = null;
> Produces:
>     firstNode -> 22 -> 44 -> null So firstNode.data is 22 and
> firstNode.next.data is 44. Since
> firstNode.next.next is null, a
> reference to  firstNode.next.next.data
> is an error.
> 
> Example 2 to practice with links: What
> is node3.data ?
>     node3 -> 99 -> null
>     Answer: 99
> 
> Example 3 to practice with links:
> public void insertIt (Node firstNode,
> Node newNode) {
>      firstNode.next = newNode;
>      newNode.next = null;  }
```

**Edit:** What happens if you assign a node to another node?

For example, head -> 2 -> 3 -> null

`node1 = node2;`

What is changing? Is `node1`s value 3? or is it changing its reference/pointer?

Comment: What do you not understand?  Is the `Node` class part of an API, or did you create it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it really doesn't make sense. `next` would have to be a public data member of the class `Node` and of type `Node`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what .next is for, so I was hoping someone can clear up my misunderstanding.

Comment: Without any context, all we can see is that `.next` is a publicly visible field of a `Node` instance. I can guess that it is of the type `Node` as well, but it would be helpful if you tell us how `Node` is defined. It looks to me a custom data type, a.k.a. not something built-in or inherent in Java.

Comment: I think it would help if you could give some information on the "Node" datatype you're using. It sounds like 'Node' contains a field for the "next" node and that there should be a method that returns a parent node's child node called next().

Could you give more detail about the problem and perhaps the code for the Node datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your comment, I think I understand what you're attempting to do.  This code is from an implementation of a [LinkedList Data Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).  You should read the wikipedia article, but in short, a linked list is made up of `Nodes` that contain a `data` element along with a pointer to the next element in the list.  Because of this, it is possible to traverse the list in order with knowledge of only the first element.  The `.next` is used to access the next data member relative to the current node.  When you insert an element, you usually need to do something like this:

```
public void insertNode(Node nodeBefore, Node newNode){
  newNode.next = nodeBefore.next;
  nodeBefore.next = newNode;
}
```

This method inserts the `Node` `newNode` after the `Node` `nodeBefore` so that when you traverse the list, after you reach `nodeBefore` you reach `newNode`.  Typically, the end of the list of signified by a `null` pointer.

**Edit** To address your comment, the class `Node` likely looks like this:

```
public class Node{
  public Node next;
  public Object data;
}
```

That is where `next` comes from.  It's a public data member of the `Node` class

Comment: Where does the `.next` come from? Is it part of a certain interface/class? I couldn't find the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are learning about linked lists... this method essentially adds another node to the end like this:

```
 firstNode          newNode
+------+------+    +------+------+
| data | next-|--->| data | null |
+------+------+    +------+------+
```